# Find position of argv value in C?

Tags: c, getopt

So I want to use argv to get command line arguments. However these arguments should be able to be in any order with the flags.

so if my command line was

```
./a.out -t textfile.txt -m mapfile.txt
```

I want to find where in argv mapfile.txt would be. I can rearrange it so it can be in position 2 or 4.

I tried doing a for loop like:

```
int pos;
for(int i = 0; i <argc; i++){
    if (argv[i] == "-t"){ //tried doing "t" as well
        pos = i;
    }
}
```

This didnt work.

Comment: `if (argv[i] == "-t")` compares _pointers_. To compare values use `if (strcmp(argv[i], "-t")==0)`